# Can't remove an app info from developer account. Version code issue

Tags: android, google-play, version

I uploaded an app to play store as alpha and then I clicked "Remove" because I forgot to shrinkResources. Now Play Store forces me to change version code to the different in order to upload it again. How can I delete information that I uploaded an app with version code 1? It seems that I signed apk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go on the sidebar to 'Release management' --> 'Artifact library' --> 'Draft artifacts' and delete it there.

Comment: Yeah, found myself:D